# Ajax : Can't bind multiple parameters

Tags: ajax

Hey I am trying to bind multiple parameters in ajax post request but I am getting the following error.
`Can't bind multiple parameters to the request's content.`
Here is my code
`MVC Api Controller Side`

```
public void Post(Email email, PInformation pInformation)
        {
//do something.
        }
```

`Ajax Call`

```
var mail = { mail: 'myemail', Password: 'pass' };
var ppInformation = { FirstName: 'James', LastName: 'Jones' };
var datum = { email: mail, pInformation: ppInformation };
$.ajax({

url: 'url',
type: 'POST',
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
dataType: "json",
data: JSON.stringify(datum),
success: function (result) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a composite, so:

```
$.ajax({
   ...
   data: {form: datum},
});
```

Your controller method:

```
public String controlerMethod(@RequestBody FormData form){
 ...
}
```

Your form model:

```
class FormData {
    Email email;
    PInformation pInformation;

    // getters & setters
}
```

This solution should work, but I can't say that there is some sort of multiple RequestBody available for POST method.